# Flutter Bluetooth Barcode Scanner Returns Incorrect Characters on my app but works fine in any other Note App

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, listener, barcode-scanner

I'm working on a Flutter app that includes barcode scanning functionality. I'm using an external barcode scanner, which works fine when scanning barcodes outside of my app (e.g., in a note-taking app). However, when I integrate the barcode scanning functionality into my Flutter app, it returns incorrect characters instead of numbers.

Here are some additional details:

I'm using [flutter_barcode_listener-0.1.3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_listener).
my phone is Samsung M32 ,Android 13.

My code:

```
Widget mainMenu() {
 return BarcodeKeyboardListener(
  bufferDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  onBarcodeScanned: (barcode)async {
    // if (!visible) return;

    print('barcode*** ${barcode}');
    // FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
  },
  child: Stack(...)
 )
}
```

When I scan the barcode using a different app, the correct numbers are displayed.
I've already Ensured that I'm using the latest version of the barcode scanning library and its dependencies.
Despite these efforts, I'm still experiencing the problem where the barcode scanner returns incorrect characters (e.g., "&é-") instead of numbers. I'm unsure where the issue lies and how to resolve it.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Link to a similar barcode scanner that I used :
https://store.cartoncloud.com/products/eyoyo-2d-back-clip-bluetooth-barcode-scanner-work-with-phone-portable-barcode-reader-with-bluetooth-function-1d-2d-qr

EDIT :
it seems that the software keyboard influences the behavior of the plugins, if the keyboard is French it works fine but if is English or Else it shows symbols.

now I'm having another problem: at the start, the listener works fine, but once the keyboard opened the call-back method is never called, after debugging the plugin, I found that the problem is the "Enter" char, the call_back is called when keyEvent = Enter, but this condition never satisfied, any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: What value are you expecting `"&é-"` to be?

Comment: I'm getting this   -&"àé"'àà&&'è    instead of this   6130234001147